# How to link to a <div> on another page?

Tags: html

I'd like that a specific link goes to a certain header on another page. I know how to do it on the current page.

Comment: Use the hash and put an id on the div. `<a href='myOtherPage.html#myDivId'>myLink</a>`

Comment: In addition to @MelanciaUK `<div id="foo"></div>` and `<a href="bar.html#foo">Go to Foo</a>`

Comment: @MelanciaUK # is a hash, not a "hashtag".

Comment: @James Donnelly: #misinformed #popularnames #terminology #whathastwitterdonetous

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Take a look at anchor tags. You can create an anchor with

```
<div id="anchor-name">Heading Text</div>
```

and refer to it later with

```
<a href="http://server/page.html#anchor-name">Link text</a>
```

Comment: The use of `<a name ...>` is declared as obsolete in HTML5 CR, and it really reflects the shortcomings of early HTML versions.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I wasn't aware of that. Has just using IDs of elements (e.g. `div`s) replaced it? Or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: Using `id` attributes is the recommended way (and has been possible for a long time, all relevant browsers support it).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the information! I've updated my answer for anyone who subsequently finds it.

Comment: Should this work on PHP too? I am not getting result on <a href="page.php#anchor-name">Link text</a>

Answer (score 8):

You simply combine the ideas of a link to another page, as with `href=foo.html`, and a link to an element on the same page, as with `href=#bar`, so that the fragment like `#bar` is written immediately after the URL that refers to another page:

```
<a href="foo.html#bar">Some nice link text</a>
```

The target is specified the same was as when linking inside one page, e.g.

```
<div id="bar">
<h2>Some heading</h2>
Some content
</div>
```

or (if you really want to link specifically to a heading only)

```
<h2 id="bar">Some heading</h2>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add **hash info** in next page url to move browser at specific position(any html element), after page is loaded.

This is can done in this way:

add hash in the url of next_page : example.com#**hashkey**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  ##get hash code at next page
  var hashcode = window.location.hash;

  ## move page to any specific position of next page(let that is div with id "hashcode")
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('div#'+hascode).offset().top},'slow');

});
```

Comment: How do you call this function, and where do you put the code? Sorry, kinda new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Create an anchor:

```
<a name="anchor" id="anchor"></a>
```

then link to it:

```
<a href="http://server/page.html#anchor">Link text</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="./container.html">
<div>anything
<h1>hello stcakoverflow<h1>
<div>
</a>
```

> now doing thos this all div are clickcable

Comment: You have no closing `</div>` or `</h1>` tags. Is this intentional?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33051734)

Comment: aside from code being syntactically incorrect, this does not answer the OP's question