# Hyperlink to a <div> on another page in PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have referred to the solution given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565644/how-to-link-to-a-div-on-another-page) but failed to make it work. I have an index.php page which says:

```
<a href="page.php#anchor-name">
```

However, this link always direct to page.php and not to #anchor-name div on that page.

Is this so because I'm trying on localhost? Whats the problem that this works on HTML but not php? Whats the solution to make this work on php?

The relevant section of the code:

```
<a class="metro-box blue-gradient normal" href="Services.php#Ecommerce">
                      <div class="metro-box-icon"><i class="icon-user"></i></div>
                      <div class="metro-box-title"><h5>Cloud Utilities</h5></div>

                  </a>
```

I want the hyperlink to land on this div on Services.php:

```
 <div class="three-fourth last-in-row" id="#ECommerce">
```

Comment: show us the code for your `div` on page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with named anchors.

In this, you can give link to a particular section in the page.

E.g.

Say, I have following divs.

```
<div id="first">Bla Bla</div>
```

And this div is far below header, you can give a link to it using hash.

```
<a href="#first">Go to First</a>
```

By clicking on the link, your respective `div` will get focused.

Comment: Works! I was absolutely unaware about named anchors.