# Redirect to another page with button or anchor in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I have a different scenario, I want to redirect the page on click event to a link/page which contains # sign inside it. when I click on it, page remain on the same location, doesn't redirect, just replace the url in url box. I guess this is because # sign, when I replace with another link without # sign it works fine. I cannot remove this from page link, How do I redirect my page? I want to perform this in jQuery

**edit:** I don't want to reload my page

**edit: not duplicate** my link is separated by slashes "/" after and before # sign, not attached with page name

link where I want to redirect

```
myApp/#/myPage.html
```

or just

```
#/myPage.html
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

or

```
<a id="btn" href="#">Click</a>
```

I tried these..

```
<button onClick="window.location='#/myPage.html';">Click</button>
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function (e) {
                    window.location.href = "myApp/#/myPage.html";  
//window.location.href = "#/myPage.html";  // this too tried
             });
```

and these

```
window.location.href = "#/myPage.html";
$(location).attr('href','#/myPage.html');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link to a <div> on another page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565644/how-to-link-to-a-div-on-another-page)

Comment: @Thomas I have a slash "/" after and before # sign

Comment: Mnagrio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html No slashes allowed

Comment: @Thomas `$(location).attr('href','myApp/directory/myPage.html');` this works fine with slashes

Comment: If you are using URLs such as `myApp/#/myPage.html`, then that surely is some kind of framework with a built-in routing system? As such, it should provide methods to go to a “different page”, which effectively seems to be what you want to do. So go check the documentation of that framework.

Comment: @CBroe I am using framework7 of HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the URL stays the same, the browser won't make a new page request. You could add some query parameter to the URL like this, the downside being slightly less pretty URL in the location bar:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function (e) {
     window.location.href = "?"+Date.now()+"#/myPage.html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this stackoverflow reply answers your question: [Javascript reload the page with hash value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value#answer-10612657)

`window.location.hash = "#/myPage.html"
location.reload();`

Comment: I even tried this, but I don't want to reload or refresh my page