# How to redirect someone with a button to a spot further on down the page?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a button that redirects someone further down the page, rather than having 10 different html pages that link from the one page (that way I have one page, instead of 10).  My code is currently this

```
    <h2>My Library:</h2>

    <h3>
        <a href="000.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">000 - Generalities</button></a>
</h3>
<h3>
    <a href="100.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">100 - Philosophy & Psychology</button></a>

    <h3>
        <a href="200.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">200 - Religion</button></a>
</h3>
<h3>
    <a href="300.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">300 - Social Sciences</button></a>
</h3>

    <h3>
        <a href="400.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">400 - Language</button></a>
</h3>
<h3>
    <a href="500.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">500 - Natural Sciences</button></a>
</h3>

    <h3>
        <a href="600.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">600 - Technology</button></a>
</h3>
<h3>
    <a href="700.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">700 - The Arts</button></a>
</h3>

    <h3>
        <a href="800.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">800 - Literature</button></a>
</h3>
<h3>
    <a href="900.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">900 - Geography & History</button></a>
</h3>

<h3>
    <a href="Unsorted.html"><button onclick="myFunction()">Unsorted</button></a>
```

Comment: Nvm, figured out how.  Needed the page id thing.  Sorry for the post.

Comment: use anchor tags <a> [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Here is a good code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20565694/9595653

Comment: This is a duplicate of  [How to link to a <div> on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565644/how-to-link-to-a-div-on-another-page)