# Render twig view on specific div

Tags: php, html, twig, anchor

I'm using Twig with PHP, I wanted to know if it's possible to render a view on a specific div.

(with the url like this : localhost/home/#contact)

To render a view I'm doing this :

Controller :

```
public function show()
    {
        ...

        echo $twig->render('home.html.twig');
    }
```

index :

```
$router->get('/', 'Home#show');
```

Comment: When the url is #contact, I want the view to go to a specific div. The content of the page does not change

Comment: Does that solve your problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link to a <div> on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565644/how-to-link-to-a-div-on-another-page)

Comment: Yes but I want this to happen when the url is loaded and not when I click somewhere

Comment: So you want to apply that to all links accessing your page? If yes, you will need to use JS OR redirect all site.com/page queries to site.com/page#my-anchor

Comment: No he doesn't, it's default browser behaviour to jump to a specific div with that ID or named anchor. Only if you want a smooth "scroll" U'd need to resort to JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I dont know if it's the best way to do it but there it is :

`header('Location: /home/#contact');`

Comment: Your issue description is not clear, unfortunately. Your solution `header('Location: /home/#contact');` is just a redirect to a Url with anchor.