# Open page with everything hidden except what the URL says to open

Tags: javascript, html, css

[How to link to a <div> on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565644/how-to-link-to-a-div-on-another-page) was showing how to [Link text](http://server/page.html#anchor-name) to a div id, but what I am looking to do is write one web page that is linked from other pages but hides all content but what the link id says to show. o page1 link to `infopage.html` with content A visible and page2 link to infopage.html with content B visible, page3 link to infopage.html with content C visible and so on. using plain `HTML`, `CSS` and `vanilla JavaScript`. no `jQuery` please; trying to learn how this would tie together. hope I explained this well enough

Comment: no as easy as that. If that is on an external site then you cant. You cant take control of another website and change its styling. Possibly you can make something work with an iframe and overwrite the styling but that also might can trigger legal actions. otherwise if you talk about your website you can use `:target` selector. Alternativly look into a SPA (Single page Application).

Comment: do you want to use the same domain like ```example.com``` then use a path to display or hide certain items like ```example.com/showCertainPart``` or use different domains to show the data specific to that domain?

Comment: Yes it is all the same domain. Front end only, and no jquery please.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `:target` selector.

You hide all the content in CSS with the use of `display: none;`. Then you can show the content when the link is clicked by using `*:target { display: block; }`

If you want to load content from other websites, you can either use `PHP include` or `iframe`. However you cant show only specific parts of the website that easily. You would need to overwrite its default styling with the same emthod mentioned above.

```css
main > div {
  display: none;
}

main > div:target {
  display: block;
}


/* For Styling Pupose only */

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#A">Content A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#B">Content B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#C">Content C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <div id="A">This is Content A</div>
  <div id="B">This is Content B</div>
  <div id="C">This is Content C</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty way to make that happen:

- all the articles are hidden by default
- window.location.href.split('#')[1] will get you the anchor name
- classList.remove('hidden') removes the hidden class from the selected article

page1.html

```html
<style> .hidden { display: none; }</style>

<div id="article1" class="hidden"><h2>Article 1</h2></div>
<div id="article2" class="hidden"><h2>Article 2</h2></div>

<p><a href="page2.html#article3">Go to Article 3</a></p>
<p><a href="page2.html#article4">Go to Article 4</a></p>

<script>
    document.querySelector(`#${window.location.href.split('#')[1]}`).classList.remove('hidden');
</script>
```

page2.html

```html
<style>.hidden { display: none; } </style>

<div id="article3" class="hidden"><h2>Article 3</h2></div>
<div id="article4" class="hidden"><h2>Article 4</h2></div>

<p><a href="page1.html#article4">Go to Article 1</a></p>
<p><a href="page1.html#article5">Go to Article 2</a></p>

<script>
    document.querySelector(`#${window.location.href.split('#')[1]}`).classList.remove('hidden');
</script>
```

Comment: multiple issues. You missing a `click EventListener` or an `onclick trigger`. Also you just display that element then forever. You need to hide them also if another link is clicked. Your samples then are not working proberly. Besides of that, way to messy and and unecessary to solve this with JS. You can use `anchor` + `:target` as pure CSS solution. Way easier/shorter, no scripting and much cleaner.

Comment: There is no need for an onclick. If you actually look at what I wrote you will see that each link only points to the other page. And the JS then extracts the anchor from the URL on load. There is also no need to hide the other content since the original poster wasn't asking about displaying content on the same page. You must have misunderstood the intent of the question.